# A method always returning null

Tags: java, android, methods

```
decibelChart.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int chartValue;
                            decibelChart.setNoDataText("Drawing Decibel Chart Error !");
                            decibelChart.setDragEnabled(false);
                            decibelChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
                            decibelChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                            decibelChart.setPinchZoom(false);
                            decibelChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            decibelChart.setData(lineData);

                            if (mediaRecorderForDB != null) {
                                chartValue = mediaRecorderForDB.getMaxAmplitude();
                            } else if (mediaRecorder != null) {
                                chartValue = mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                            } else
                                chartValue = 0;

                            LineData myData = decibelChart.getData();

                            if (myData != null) {
                                ILineDataSet set = myData.getDataSetByIndex(0);

                                if (set == null){
                                    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(null,"Dynamic");
                                    dataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
                                    dataSet.setLineWidth(3f);
                                    dataSet.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
                                    dataSet.setCubicIntensity(1f);
                                    myData.addDataSet(dataSet);
                                }

                                myData.addEntry(new Entry(set.getEntryCount(), chartValue + 5), 0);
                                myData.notifyDataChanged();
                                decibelChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(150);
                                decibelChart.moveViewToX(myData.getEntryCount());
                            }

                            Log.e("[CHART_ERROR]", "CHART DRAWING");

                        }
                    },250);
```

`set.getEntryCount()` returns null and throws exception. How can i get over it ? I tried a lot things but cannot achived.
The values are coming from the microphone they are decibel values. I want to draw a line chart for these values.

Comment: you have `ILineDataSet set = myData.getDataSetByIndex(0);` and then `if (set == null)` but you never change the value of set if it _is_ null, so why _wouldn't_ it be null still

Comment: No it didn't answer my question. Still need help.

Comment: did you read my first comment, any response you'd like to make regarding that ?

Comment: Please undo your edit so that the answer below makes sense. You still need your question there to help future people.

Comment: i've done a rollback like @NomadMaker suggested, please consider the fact that this community isn't just here to help you out, it's for people in future as well having the same issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go over it line by line

```
if (myData != null) {  //here you ask if myData is NOT null
    ILineDataSet set = myData.getDataSetByIndex(0);
    if (set == null){ // here you ask if set IS null 
        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(null,"Dynamic"); //If set IS null you create the dataset
        //....
        myData.addDataSet(dataSet);
    }
    myData.addEntry(new Entry(set.getEntryCount(), chartValue + 5), 0); //what happens if set is still null? It will thow exception
}
```

A possible solution would be

```
if (myData != null) {  //here you ask if myData is NOT null
    ILineDataSet set = myData.getDataSetByIndex(0);
    if (set == null){ // here you ask if set IS null 
        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(null,"Dynamic"); //If set IS null you create the dataset
        //....
        myData.addDataSet(dataSet);
        myData.addEntry(new Entry(dataSet.getEntryCount(), chartValue + 5), 0); //here we are sure dataSet is not null because you created it
    } else { // this means set is NOT null
        myData.addEntry(new Entry(set.getEntryCount(), chartValue + 5), 0); //here we are sure set is not null because it is the ELSE for the IS NULL question
    }
    myData.notifyDataChanged();
    decibelChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(150);
    decibelChart.moveViewToX(myData.getEntryCount());
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) But i am getting "java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -6" error now do you have any idea ? I am getting these types of errors first time sorry for my silly questions.

Comment: Don't worry. This error means you have an array, which is basically a collection of things with an index that starts with 0 and ends with n-1 (n being the number of elements you have). For example an array of 4 letters could be [A|B|C|D] so, index 0 = A, index 1 = B, index 2 = C and index 3 = D. 
As you can see there are no negative indexes in an array so the error is saying that there is an array and it is trying to get the index -6 which, of course, does not exist. 
In this code I don't see where this could be happening so I think it happens on another place of your code. @FanFiniFinFon